# iPhone screen zoomed without zoom accessibility feature

Tags: ios, iphone

My iPhone 6 screen is awkwardly zoomed in (not on the zoom screen function) and I can't access the edges of my screen. How can I fix this? I can't access my space bar when texting or my Notification Center. Tried restarting and charging but nothing has worked. Any tips?

Comment: Did you try hard reset?  Hold power and home, about 20 seconds until you  see the the reboot start.

Comment: If someone with this issue wants to upload a screen shot - feel free to edit this. Also - asking a new question and linking here might help if your situation is different.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say "without the zoom accessibility feature"? That's almost certainly what has happened; that feature has been activated. Try 3-finger tapping to unzoom your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your device to iTunes and you can disable all accessibility features from the connected computer. The other answer is great for disabling the features from the iOS device which is easier for most people unless the zoom factor is too large to work the device.